# How can I solve this MYSQL INSERT INTO query error?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when I try to insert something in my MySQL database.

Here is the error:

> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1 - Invalid query: INSERT INTO `banlog` (`ID`, `ip`, `player`, `admin`, `reason`, `day`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, 'Offline','4Gamers','4Gamers','3/3 warns', '3' , '2019-10-13 23:42:09') LIMIT 1

Here is the code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `banlog` (`ID`, `ip`, `player`, `admin`, `reason`, `day`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, 'Offline',?,?,'3/3 warns', '3' , '$time') LIMIT 1", array($info['name'], getUserData($this->session->userdata('logged_in')["id"], "name")));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `LIMIT 1` supposed to do in this statement?

Comment: To LIMIT the inserted rows to 1.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Problem solved. I just removed the LIMIT 1 and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `LIMIT 1`.
I hope this will solve your problem.